# How do i create a conditional statement comparing a string length?

Tags: java, string

i´m studying java with bluej and the object oriented guid book  pretty we'll and i got stuck on this especific part of the exercise: "setRefNumber mutator so that it sets the refNumber field only if the parameter is a string of at least three characters. If it is less than three, then print an error message and leave the field unchanged."
 what i have try to do:

```
 public void setRefNumber (String ref)
{
    refnumber = ref;
    if (len < 3) {
        System.out.println("reference number must have at least 3 characters");
    }
    else {       
     refnumber = ref;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually use the function length() which is a part of the string library.  See below.  Should fix your problems

```
public void setRefNumber (String ref)
{
refnumber = ref;
if (ref.length() < 3) {
    System.out.println("reference number must have at least 3 characters");
}
else {       
 refnumber = ref;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the refNumber after checking whether the length is greater than 3 so you need to use the java.lang.String function 'length()'. You can check the length of ref String by the code 'ref.length()'. From this you can check if the length is greater than 3.

Also, you need not assign 'refNumber' variable before checking the length of 'ref' variable. You can just remove that line as you would be assigning the value only when length is greater than 3, so the line seems redundant.

You can see the code below:

```
public void setRefNumber (String ref)
{
   //not needed   
   //refnumber = ref;
   if (ref.length() < 3) {
       System.out.println("reference number must have at least 3 characters");
   }
   else { 
       //refNumber being asssigned here      
       refnumber = ref;
   }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the code and your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setRefNumber (String ref)
{
  if (ref.length() < 3) {
        System.out.println("reference number must have at least 3 characters");
    }
    else {       
     refnumber = ref;// only when ref's length >=3
    }
```

you can directly test the String's length in if condition and then create the conditional if-else block accordingly.